# Мы можем считать Git локальная система контроля версий

Tags: git

Почему git это рскв. но и мы можем создать локальному репозиторий

---

Git является ли распределённая VCS локальной, если не пользоваться её сетевыми функциями

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: мы знаем что  git -это  распределенный система контроля версии. Но и мы без какой нибудь web servis-и(Github, Bitbuket..) можем создать репозитории. Поэтому мы можем сказать git это распределенный и локальный скв

Comment: @NozimRustamov, на будущее: такие уточнения стоит вносить прямо в вопрос нажав серенькую кнопочку [edit].

Answer (score 5):

Под *локальными* VCS обычно понимают те, в которых принципиально отсутствует возможность взаимодействия с другими репозитариями по сети. А *распределённым* VCS (таким как `git`, `mercurial` и т.д.) обычно противопоставляют *централизованные* (такие как `cvs` или `svn`), где история изменений хранится преимущественно только на основном сервере.

Вопрос «*является ли распределённая VCS локальной, если не пользоваться её сетевыми функциями*» лежит скорее в философской плоскости и сродни вопросу «*если шурупы начать забивать молотком, превращаются ли они в гвозди*». Я бы сказал, что, скорее, *нет*.

---

- [Разъяснение понятий от Git](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/%D0%92%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%9E-%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B9)

Comment: Аналогия с шурупами клевая :)

Comment: ИМХО, шуруп забитый молотком - это скорее svn с локальным сервером и доступом к нему по протоколу `file://`. А git больше похож на ударный шуруп, у которого и закручивание и забивание является штатным методом.